# Offline.js Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, offline.js

I am use `Offline.js`. Offline.js is a library to automatically alert your users when they've lost internet connectivity. I have used the offline.js version 0.5.0.0, I have set the offline.min.js in _Layout Page. It's worked perfectly in google chrome but in `Mozilla`, some pages not worked perfectly. I have used the `Ajax request` to handle form submit event. So when ever submit successfully done then redirect to another page (my Ajax request code is as below). 
In this situation, `offline.min.js` executed automatically and give message internet is lost but internet is working fine. This issue appear only in Mozilla. Please provide me help for same.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "Post",
    url: 'ajaxrequest',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data: $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function (response)
    {
        location.href = newpage;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

> Note to users pre-0.6.0: Offline previously used a cloudfront hosted
>   file as one of it's methods of detecting the connection status. This
>   method is now deprecated. Please upgrade to Offline 0.7.0+.
>
> Note that the cloudfront file will be removed at the end of March,
>   please upgrade before then.

Straight from: [Link](https://github.com/hubspot/offline)

Comment: I have used offline 0.7.0 but still that issue occuer.